# ng-click in radiobutton not getting invoked

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the value when radio button is clicked. the controller gets loaded however the function defined in the controller is not getting executed when the click event is executed.
What am i missing here?

My code:
**JS**

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('tramsConsole',[])
        .controller('TremorController', TremorController);

    TremorController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];

    function TremorController($scope, $log,tremorService) {
        var vm = this;
        console.log("controller loaded");
        vm.getstatus = getstatus;

        function getstatus(obj){
            vm.status = obj.value;
            alert("clicked");
            console.log(obj);
        }

    }        
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="tramsConsole">
    <div ng-controller="TremorController as tremorController">
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_ERRORS" ng-click="getstatus($event)">NUM_ERRORS<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="getstatus($event)">NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_T_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="getstatus($event)">NUM_T_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="getstatus($event)">NUM_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="getstatus($event)">AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.UB_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="getstatus($event)">UB_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.T_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="getstatus($event)">T_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="getstatus($event)">UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="getstatus($event)">T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="getstatus($event)">SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>

  </div>
  </body>
```

The working copy in plunker :[Working Copy](http://plnkr.co/edit/U9WubU4UpUrlru8zBYvA?p=preview)

Comment: Try `tremorController.getstatus($event)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your method in html like this

> tremorController.getstatus($event)

when ever using **controllerAs** syntax you must able to access methods and variables by object otherwise it will refer **parent scope** objects.

Comment: yes, it is working. Not sure why we have to specify the controller name here. since we have included in the div, it should automatically take right?

Comment: Refer this (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `controller as`, then the `$scope` is attached to the controller object itself.

So basically you should change the `ng-controller` tag to:

```html
<div ng-controller="TremorController as vm">
```

And change the `ng-click` to

```html
ng-click="vm.getstatus($event)"
```

and it will work.

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/zYqk5pciy8oxIMv28CXx?p=preview

Read more at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the html reference to your controller.

```
    <div ng-controller="TremorController as tremorController">
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_ERRORS" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">NUM_ERRORS<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_T_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">NUM_T_OCCURRENCES<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">NUM_OCCURRENCES<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.UB_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">UB_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.T_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">T_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
        <input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus($event)">SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>

  </div>
```

They key is **tremorController**.getstatus($event)

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4C64h0rtbvemoDTBldMC?p=preview)

Comment: I think you should take a look at my answer, your code is inconsistent this way, because in the controller, the vm is named vm, but in the view, the vm is named tremorController.

Comment: The `controller as` name doesn't need to be the same as the controller `this`(vm). That's why in the ng-click I put tremorController instead of vm. If you check the plunker you'll see that it works.

Comment: I didn't say it does not work, I just said that it is inconsistent. Why would you name your view model not `vm`?

Comment: I don't know. Just copied what the OP posted and told him what was the error. I don't know what is the nomeclature convention the OP is using, so I prefer not put my opinion on it. But yes, the controller as name should be vm.